# F# OleDb Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Statement Pulling Data from Access to Linked SQL Server

Tags: f#, sql-server-2008-r2, oledb, ms-access-2010, insert-into

I'm running an F# application to pull data from an Access table to a linked SQL Server table. Here is the resulting query:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo_TempTerm (UnitID, PolicyTermYear, InsuredName, PolicyNumber, RenewalDate, CovATotal, CovBTotal, CovLTotal, DwellExtn, AllOtherPerilDeductible, MedPay, TotalPremium, HurricaneDeductible, Zone, Subzone, PercentCRC, PercentCRD, YearBuilt, RenYrs, PercentCFD, PercentHA, PercentMLD, GRP1, PercentNH, QCLM, RateV, CRI, AgentCode, AgentName, AFOCode, PolicyType, PolicyForm, OC, DateCreated)
SELECT [UNIT ID], [POLICY TERM YEAR], [INSURED NAME], [POLICY #], [RENEWAL DT], [COV A TOTAL], [COV B TOTAL], [COV L TOTAL], [DWELL EXTN], [ALL/OTHER PERIL DEDUCTIBLE], [MED PAY], [TOT PREMIUM], [HURR DED], ZONE, SUBZONE, [%CRC], [%CRD], [YR BLT], RENYRS, [%CFD], [%HA], [%MLD], GRP1, [%NH], QCLM, [RATE V], CRI, [AGENT CODE], [AGENT NAME], [AFO CODE], [POLICY TYPE], [POLICY FORM], OC, DateCreated
FROM tblPrior
```

The query parses and runs fine in Access. But from within my application, it raises an error: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Here is my F#, though I don't think it's relevant.

```ml
module Data

open System.Data
open System.Data.OleDb

type Period = Prior | Current

let Upload (p:Period) db =
    use conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + db + ";Persist Security Info=False;")

    let execNonQuery s =
        let comm = new OleDbCommand(s, conn) in
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore

    let (table,proc) = match p with
                       | Prior   -> ("tblPrior"  ,"InitPriorTable")
                       | Current -> ("tblCurrent","InitCurrentTable")

    do conn.Open()

    let u = sprintf "INSERT INTO dbo_TempTerm (UnitID, PolicyTermYear, InsuredName, PolicyNumber, RenewalDate, CovATotal, CovBTotal, CovLTotal, DwellExtn, AllOtherPerilDeductible, MedPay, TotalPremium, HurricaneDeductible, Zone, Subzone, PercentCRC, PercentCRD, YearBuilt, RenYrs, PercentCFD, PercentHA, PercentMLD, GRP1, PercentNH, QCLM, RateV, CRI, AgentCode, AgentName, AFOCode, PolicyType, PolicyForm, OC, DateCreated) SELECT [UNIT ID], [POLICY TERM YEAR], [INSURED NAME], [POLICY #], [RENEWAL DT], [COV A TOTAL], [COV B TOTAL], [COV L TOTAL], [DWELL EXTN], [ALL/OTHER PERIL DEDUCTIBLE], [MED PAY], [TOT PREMIUM], [HURR DED], ZONE, SUBZONE, [%%CRC], [%%CRD], [YR BLT], RENYRS, [%%CFD], [%%HA], [%%MLD], GRP1, [%%NH], QCLM, [RATE V], CRI, [AGENT CODE], [AGENT NAME], [AFO CODE], [POLICY TYPE], [POLICY FORM], OC, DateCreated FROM %s" table
    // DEBUG.
    printfn "%s" u
    // DEBUG.
    execNonQuery u
    execNonQuery proc
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the query to pull data from access and insert into SQl server directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Zone` and `DateCreated` are both [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  It's difficult to predict when reserved words will cause trouble for SQL statements, but it seems to me that OleDb may be less forgiving, ie more likely to fail with reserved words.  See if bracketing all occurrences of those names will allow the `INSERT` to succeed.

```
let u = sprintf "INSERT INTO dbo_TempTerm (UnitID, PolicyTermYear, InsuredName, PolicyNumber, RenewalDate, CovATotal, CovBTotal, CovLTotal, DwellExtn, AllOtherPerilDeductible, MedPay, TotalPremium, HurricaneDeductible, [Zone], Subzone, PercentCRC, PercentCRD, YearBuilt, RenYrs, PercentCFD, PercentHA, PercentMLD, GRP1, PercentNH, QCLM, RateV, CRI, AgentCode, AgentName, AFOCode, PolicyType, PolicyForm, OC, [DateCreated]) SELECT [UNIT ID], [POLICY TERM YEAR], [INSURED NAME], [POLICY #], [RENEWAL DT], [COV A TOTAL], [COV B TOTAL], [COV L TOTAL], [DWELL EXTN], [ALL/OTHER PERIL DEDUCTIBLE], [MED PAY], [TOT PREMIUM], [HURR DED], [ZONE], SUBZONE, [%%CRC], [%%CRD], [YR BLT], RENYRS, [%%CFD], [%%HA], [%%MLD], GRP1, [%%NH], QCLM, [RATE V], CRI, [AGENT CODE], [AGENT NAME], [AFO CODE], [POLICY TYPE], [POLICY FORM], OC, [DateCreated] FROM %s" table
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. I'll check the list of reserved words next time I see another non-sense error like this one.

Comment: You're welcome, Jeff.  Near the top of the page I linked, there is a link for *Database Issue Checker Utility*.  You could download that utility and use it to inspect your Access databases.  It will warn you about problem object names, and also other issues which can create trouble.