# How to connect to a Microsoft Access database .mdb on my local computer with F# 3.0 type provider SqlDataConnection?

Tags: database, ms-access, f#, type-providers

I would like to use a new feature of the F# 3.0 programming language: type provider. 
I tried to connect to a Microsoft Access database .mdb on a local computer with F# 3.0 type provider SqlDataConnection, but the type provider reported an error: "Keyword not supported: 'provider'" and failed to connect to the database. The database has no password.

My F# code is:

```ml
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders 
open System.Data.Linq.SqlClient
open System.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

// I found the connection string in database properties in the Server Explorer window 
// in Visual Studio 2012 
[<Literal>] 
let conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\FM Access\FM Day.mdb;" 
type schema = SqlDataConnection<conn>
```

Please help me solve that type-provider problem. What's wrong with my connection string? Or maybe I need another type provider? Is there any type provider supporting connections to a  Microsoft Access database .mdb in F# 3.0?

Comment: Instead of using `SqlClient` and/or `SqlDataConnection` perhaps you should be using `OleDbClient` and/or `OleDbConnection`? `Sql...` things might be specific to SQL Server.

Comment: SqlDataConnection is type provider only for SQL server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362320.aspx I don't know if type provider exists for Access.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in my comment to the question, I think you need to be using `OleDbConnection` and related objects. There is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15815934/2144390) with some sample code that might help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and hyperlink to useful code. But I tried to use a new language feature (type provider) instead of OleDbConnection class. It is as if Microsoft does not adequately support its own software product (MS Access) in another product (F#), and the programming language lacks support for connections to MS Access databases with type providers. Do you know where I can download a type provider for working with MS Access databases (.mdb)?

Comment: @AlekseyOdeychuk Sorry but no, I'm not aware of any such type provider. I believe that in the early days of LINQ there were high hopes that it would be extended beyond SQL Server to support many other database platforms, but as far as I know most of them just didn't happen.

Comment: There is no OleDb type provider today. If you think it would be useful, you should look into authoring one, and add it to FSharp.Data (http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Data/) or FSharpX(https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx). Microsoft develops and/or supports literally hundreds of technologies and APIs, and obviously there can't be a Microsoft-supported F# type provider for all of them. F# OleDb users who are not willing to use the existing standard OleDb API is a very small market :)

Comment: @latkin Thanks for the confirmation and comments. I don't use F# myself, but perhaps some other F# user might take up the cause of authoring such a provider.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, latkin - Thank you very much for your willingness to help and useful information!

Answer (score 2):

For whatever it's worth I connected an F# app to a local Access instance and it was just quicker and easier to use direct ODBC. I've put up a [gist](https://gist.github.com/OnorioCatenacci/6917875) of my code but this is the salient part:

```
open System
open System.Data.Odbc


let connectToAccess filename =
    let connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;FileDSN=" + filename + ";User Id=admin;Password=;"
    new OdbcConnection(connectionString)

let connectToDb() =
    let userProfileDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile")
    let accessFile = userProfileDir + @"\Documents\FortuneCookie.accdb"
    connectToAccess accessFile
```

In this particular case, I think a type provider is probably more effort than it's worth; likewise OleDB.  ODBC serves the purpose just fine.